# Почему ставится запятая перед союзом "или" при описании другими словами?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

1. Его звали Григорий(,) или обычно Гриша.
2. Это была зеленая скала(,) или, другими словами, скала Дондон.
3. "Меня называют Александр Петрович(,) или просто Сашуля".

Согласно какому правилу здесь ставятся запятые? Никак не могу загулить нужное правило.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Согласно какому правилу здесь ставятся запятые?

См.:

**§ 64. Обособляются запятыми приложения, имеющие при себе присоединяющие их слова** (*по имени, по фамилии, по прозвищу, по происхождению, родом* и др.), а также союзы *как* (при осложненности причинным значением) и ***или*** (при пояснительном значении): <…> *Лидия, **или**, как ее звали дома, **Лида**, говорила больше с Белокуровым, чем со мной (Ч.).*

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120